# Delegated Hyper-V Management

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, delegation

I have a small, clustered Hyper-V infrastructure and one of my clients has 7 VMs with me currently. Their IT person would like to get console access to the instances, so if something freezes (as an example) he can login to the host and reboot the box. Is it possible to give him access to do this, while also restricting which VMs he can see? That way he can't accidentally touch one he shouldn't.

I know I could write a web interface for this that allows for rebooting and such with WMI management, but I'm hoping there is an easier alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible, I am also pretty sure it is pretty complex to setup, also everything changes once you go to Hyper-V 2016.  Anyway, I think you have to do something with the 'Authorization Manager' - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2008/01/17/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-v/